# customize approval step email template notification

Tags: approval-process

I have an approval process with multiple steps. In some of the  steps, the assigned approver is a queue and in other steps, the assigned approver is a related user. The approval notification that goes out for each step allows the approver to reply back and approve from the email when the assigned approver is a related user. It does not work when the assigned approver is a queue.

I'm aware of automatically assigning to approvers, but those approvers can change which would mean updating the approval process. The preference is to keep it to a queue.

Is there a solution that would allow a different approval notification to be sent when the approval step is sending to a queue instead of a related user?